# KMP algorithm-Time complexity

Tags: algorithm

Finding the time complexity of pre processing part of the kmp algorithm

I'm studying about KMP. But I can't understand time complexity of this algorithm.Can anyone explain this?

Comment: At least provide code which you are referring to and highlight the part where you are facing difficulty. Your question doesn't follow the guidelines as well.

Comment: Please show a little effort in your questions. If you're struggling to understand the complexity please explain more precisely what your struggling to understand and why.

Answer (score 1):

We're trying to calculate values of function often called PI.

First, let's define our PI function. Let S be our string. PI(i) = x <=> x is the length of the longest suffix of a substring of S starting at S's first character and ending on S's i-th character that is also S's prefix.

Example:

S:   AAABACD

PI:  0120100

Let S(i) be a prefix of S of length i.

Let's say we already have all the values PI(1), PI(2), ..., PI(i - 1). The time complexity of calculating PI(i) is O(n).
We try to extend the longest prefix and suffix for S(i - 1).
If that's possible, we just do it, so PI(i) = PI(i - 1) + 1.
If not, we are trying the longest prefix and suffix of the longest prefix and suffix (however weird it may sound), and so on. It is obvious that the length of new substring we are trying to extend is at least 1 less than the previous one.
When we reach substring of length 0, then PI(i) = 0.
That is why the complexity of this step is O(n).

Because we calculate PI(i) for all 1 <= i <= n, the complexity is O(n^2)... or is it?

Let's talk about amortized complexity.
Since each time we try another prefix and suffix we decrease the length of an examined substring by at least 1, we will certainly stop our algorithm after no more than PI(i - 1) - 1 steps.
Let x be number of times we tried another prefix and suffix for all 1 <= j <= i - 1. Then PI(i - 1) <= i - 2 - x. (if x = 0 then PI(j) = PI(j - 1) + 1 for all 1 <= j <= i - 1. After we've made x additional trials we've decreased the value of PI(j) for some j by at least x.)
We can see that x < n, so in total, we made up to O(n) additional steps in our algorithm. That is why amortized complexity is equal to O(n).

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity of KMP is O(n).
KMP  has an inner loop and an outer loop. The longest matching prefix variable i is initialized with 0 and it is incremented in steps of 1 in the outer loop at most n times, the length of the text string.
The inner loop iteratively decreases i , but it stops at 0.
Hence the inner loop can only decrease i  when the outer loop has previously incremented it which can happen at most n times.

You can think of the value of i  as a resource that is produced by the outer loop in steps of 1 and consumed by the inner loop in steps of  ⩾1  until it is exhausted.